# Динамическое создание формы в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день. У меня имеется вот такая простенькая форма добавления игрока в базу данных:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Player</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="newPlayer">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PositionId, "Позиция", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("PositionId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Position, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeamId, "Команда", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("TeamId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeamId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Добавить" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Ничего особенного, для начинающего освоить - самое то. Но у меня возникла идея добавлять игроков не о одному, а сразу несколько. Допустим, чтобы была кнопка "Еще один игрок", которая динамически добавляют на страницу еще одну форму. Подскажите как это проще сделать или в сторону каких технологий глядеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так.

Код всей формы пишите на чистом HTML, без razor и закидываете в строковую переменную.

```
var formTemplate = `<div>
  <input name="hallo[1]">
  ...
  </div>`;
```

Далее при нажатии на кнопку динамически добавляется в конец определённого блока код `formTemplate`, С заменёнными частью [1] эта часть нужны для однозначной идентификации формы каждого пользователя.

```
var pleerForm = document.createElement("div");
pleerForm.innerHTML = formTemplate.replace("[1]",currentPlayerFormNumber);
document.getElementById("my-form").append(pleerForm);
```

Но вот с валидацией придётся свой кастомный механизм реализовывать.

**Второй подход** это это первую форму создать как вы делали на Razor а последующие клонировать от неё.
После клонирования сделать замену в именах на новый индекс.

**Третий подход** использование `vue.js`, это фреймворк для создания одностраничных приложений, но подходит и для отдельных страниц.

Минус этого подхода - много разбираться, но польза может быть огромна.

**Четвёртый подход**, возможно не полнофункциональный как выше, но наиболее простой. Прямо через Razor сгенерировать например 10 (или другое число) частей формы сразу, без возможности добавлять. Возможно для конкретной задачи этого вполне хватит.